# Proof concerning Cartesian products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Anyone here who could help me out with the following exercise? It is very clear to me why it holds up with Euler diagrams (under the assumption of strict subsets), but I just can't seem to work out the proof, and our textbook doesn't provide a solution. Here it goes:
"Show that when 
  
    
      A
      ⊆
      
        A
        ′
      
    
  
 and 
  
    
      B
      ⊆
      
        B
        ′
      
    
  
, then 
  
    
      A
      ×
      B
      ⊆
      
        A
        ′
      
      ×
      
        B
        ′
      
    
  
. "

Comment: Suppose that $(a,b)\in (A\times B)$.  Then $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  Since $A\subseteq A'$ then $a\in A'$.  Similarly since $B\subseteq B'$... and finally as a result this implies that $(a,b)\in$... Therefore...

Comment: I'm assuming that you copy-pasted those characters. It might be more convenient to become familiar with MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a,b)\in A\times B.$ Then, $a\in A\subseteq A'\implies a\in A'$ and $b\in B\subseteq B'\implies b\in B'.$ That is, $(a,b)\in A'\times B'.$